# sliding window data with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sliding-window

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df = DataFrame(dict(month = [1,2,3,4,5,6], a = [2,4,2,4,2,4], b = [3,5,6,3,4,6]))
```

[image]

what I want is a function that can take a window size as input and give me something like this:

function :  `def make_sliding_df(data, size)`

1. If I do `make_sliding_df(df, 1)` the output should be a Dataframe like this:

[image]

2. If I do `make_sliding_df(df, 2)` the output should be a Dataframe like this:

[image]

I have tried a bunch of things but none have helped me so far, any help would be appreciated.(I have checked few other similar questions, but none helped out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `shift`, `applymap` and `reduce`

```
In [2007]: def make_sliding(df, N):
      ...:     dfs = [df.shift(-i).applymap(lambda x: [x]) for i in range(0, N+1)]
      ...:     return reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y), dfs)
      ...:

In [2008]: make_sliding(df, 1)
Out[2008]:
          a         b     month
0  [2, 4.0]  [3, 5.0]  [1, 2.0]
1  [4, 2.0]  [5, 6.0]  [2, 3.0]
2  [2, 4.0]  [6, 3.0]  [3, 4.0]
3  [4, 2.0]  [3, 4.0]  [4, 5.0]
4  [2, 4.0]  [4, 6.0]  [5, 6.0]
5  [4, nan]  [6, nan]  [6, nan]

In [2009]: make_sliding(df, 2)
Out[2009]:
               a              b          month
0  [2, 4.0, 2.0]  [3, 5.0, 6.0]  [1, 2.0, 3.0]
1  [4, 2.0, 4.0]  [5, 6.0, 3.0]  [2, 3.0, 4.0]
2  [2, 4.0, 2.0]  [6, 3.0, 4.0]  [3, 4.0, 5.0]
3  [4, 2.0, 4.0]  [3, 4.0, 6.0]  [4, 5.0, 6.0]
4  [2, 4.0, nan]  [4, 6.0, nan]  [5, 6.0, nan]
5  [4, nan, nan]  [6, nan, nan]  [6, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 2):

This by using `numpy`, this may look ugly, but it is my first try with `numpy`...

```
def make_sliding_df(df,step=1,width=2):
    l=[]
    for x in df.columns:
        a=df[x]
        a=np.array(a)
        b=np.append(a,[np.nan]*(width-1))
        l.append((b[(np.arange(width)[None, :] + step*np.arange(len(a))[:, None])]).tolist())
    newdf=pd.DataFrame(data=l).T
    newdf.columns=df.columns
    return(newdf)

make_sliding_df(df,step=1,width=2)
Out[157]: 
            a           b       month
0  [2.0, 4.0]  [3.0, 5.0]  [1.0, 2.0]
1  [4.0, 2.0]  [5.0, 6.0]  [2.0, 3.0]
2  [2.0, 4.0]  [6.0, 3.0]  [3.0, 4.0]
3  [4.0, 2.0]  [3.0, 4.0]  [4.0, 5.0]
4  [2.0, 4.0]  [4.0, 6.0]  [5.0, 6.0]
5  [4.0, nan]  [6.0, nan]  [6.0, nan]

make_sliding_df(df,step=1,width=3)
Out[158]: 
                 a                b            month
0  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0]  [3.0, 5.0, 6.0]  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
1  [4.0, 2.0, 4.0]  [5.0, 6.0, 3.0]  [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
2  [2.0, 4.0, 2.0]  [6.0, 3.0, 4.0]  [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
3  [4.0, 2.0, 4.0]  [3.0, 4.0, 6.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
4  [2.0, 4.0, nan]  [4.0, 6.0, nan]  [5.0, 6.0, nan]
5  [4.0, nan, nan]  [6.0, nan, nan]  [6.0, nan, nan]
```